# mount proc filestsrem inside namespace

Tags: linux, namespace, container

I had a rootfs of a linux os (like ubuntu or centos) and removed  `mount` command inside that .

now, is there any way to mount proc filesystem with `nsenter` or `unshare` or any other command inside a container ?

I used this simple commands for create a container :

```
# Create Container
unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc chroot rootfs /bin/bash 

# Get pid of namespace
pgrep -P $(pgrep unshare)
```

Now I want to mount proc filesystem inside the container but container have not `mount` command.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Consider also docker.

Comment: From your question, you say that you can not do it because of no `mount` command, therefore add  `mount` command.

Comment: I want do that outside of container .

Comment: also if this is for security consider this: http://www.ouah.org/chroot-break.html . doing chroot after the namespace change won't prevent to revert to / if access to external code is possible